# Problem in reference js file for IE7/8

Tags: asp.net, javascript, internet-explorer

I have a very strange problem in an ASP.NET page, the following reference of JavaScript file works well in IE6

```
<script src='~/Scripts/xxx.js'  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But not working in IE7/8, I got object required error when load the page
change to the following works:

```
<script src='<%# ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/xxx.js") %>'  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/ is not going to be anything the browser knows about, it needs to be a relative path or an absolute one.  The ResolveUrl method take an asp.net path and creates one the browser can understand.

Comment: but why it works in IE6? I tried <script src='../Scripts/xxx.js'  type="text/javascript"></script> 
Also can't work in IE7/8

Comment: I would say it works in IE6 because IE6 is not standards compliant, IE7/8 are more standards compliant.  what is the location of the page this is on and what is the location of the script.  i usually use absolute paths to my scripts so URL rewriting and other factors don't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<script src="<%= Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/Scripts/xxx.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Basically, the "~" is a way to refer to the application's home directory, but it is only understood by ASP.NET.  You can call the function I listed above to translate that into a real HTTP path.